# Lightningchart js - How i can rotate tick text?

Tags: rotation, axis, lightningchart

Is it possible in lightningchart js to rotate ticks text on axis? Ticks text does not fit or overlaps adjacent text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of LightningChart JS v3.1.0 it's possible to set tick label rotation.

You can use [`axis.setTickStyle`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/axis.html#settickstyle) to set style settings for current tick strategy. Alternatively this can be done through [`axis.setTickStrategy`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/axis.html#settickstrategy)'s `styler` parameter.

The [`VisibleTicks`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/visibleticks.html) class has [`setLabelRotation`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/visibleticks.html#setlabelrotation) method which can be used to define tick rotation in degrees. Positive angle rotates clockwise and negative angle counter-clockwise. So to rotate labels on X axis to be rotated vertically.

```js
chart.getDefaultAxisX()
    .setTickStyle((s) => s
        .setMajorTickStyle((m) => m.setLabelRotation(-90))
        .setMinorTickStyle(m => m.setLabelRotation(-90)),
    )
```

See full example below.

```js
const {
  lightningChart,
  PointShape,
} = lcjs

const pointSize = 10

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

chart.addPointLineSeries()
  .setPointSize(pointSize)
  .add([{
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    {
      x: 50,
      y: 10
    },
    {
      x: 80,
      y: 20
    },
    {
      x: 100,
      y: 30
    },
    {
      x: 150,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 180,
      y: 50
    },
    {
      x: 230,
      y: 60
    },
    {
      x: 290,
      y: 70
    }
  ])

chart.addPointLineSeries({
    pointShape: PointShape.Circle
  })
  .setPointSize(pointSize)
  .add([{
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    {
      x: 100,
      y: 10
    },
    {
      x: 230,
      y: 20
    },
    {
      x: 390,
      y: 30
    },
    {
      x: 470,
      y: 40
    },
    {
      x: 540,
      y: 50
    },
    {
      x: 600,
      y: 60
    },
    {
      x: 800,
      y: 70
    }
  ])

chart.getDefaultAxisX()
  .setInterval(0, 1000, false, true)
  .setTickStyle((s) =>
    s.setMajorTickStyle((m) => m.setLabelRotation(-90)).setMinorTickStyle(m => m.setLabelRotation(-90)),
  )
chart.getDefaultAxisY()
  .setInterval(0, 100, false, true)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.1.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great news! thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

As of current version (v3.0.1) there is no API for configuring text.

I see this as a very potential feature improvement. It would help us in introducing it to the library, if you would describe your usage case for rotated tick text.

Screenshots are gold.